# How to change the language of a website in php

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching over the internet about this problem a week ago but I could not get the exact answer.  I went to my friends who are also web developers but they could not give me the right answer.

I just want to know how to change the language of my website to the desired language by the user. In my case, I used drop down button and if the user change the language, let's say for example, from English to Chinese vv, the website's text will change to automatically chinese. These, texts came from the database.

Does anybody know about this? Need much help. thanks

Comment: There are 1000 ways to do this. With the given information it is impossible to tell what your specific question is. "How to translate a site" it just too broad to answer.

Comment: What do you have so far?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need load different text from a database according to users selection (usually stored as session data). For very small list such as menu text, you can store them in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change front end text and has no functionality of storing that in database, then i will recommend you to use google translate tool for the websites.

Refer this link for the plugin: https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **i18n** to create a multilingual website. To do this follow the link

http://www.onlinetutz.com/create-a-multilingual-website-using-php-with-i18n/

it helps you!!